# find & copy command is not copying same number of files

Tags: command-line, find, cp, clipboard, exec

I'm trying to use find & copy on some files but the problem is if i only run find command and check wc it shows some result, after copying these files to some other directories it shows some other result (number of files)

here you can get the clear picture of problem:

```
[root@localhost student]# find /tmp/files/test/ -type f -size -1000c | wc
    664     664   19863
```

you can see that it shows 664 files that matches the criteria of size, now i copied it to some directory

```
[root@localhost student]# find /tmp/files/test/ -type f -size -1000c -exec cp {} /tmp/files/pictures/ \;
```

after copying i check the files count

```
[root@localhost student]# ls -l /tmp/files/pictures/ | wc
    657    5906   36049
```

in that file i only have 657 files, why ?

how do i compare both which files were not copied ?

and there's no verbose option in man page of find.

Comment: Do you have files with hidden names? `find` would see these, but `ls` without `-a` or `-A` would not.  Also note that `ls` would output one extra line, three (on most filesystems) if you use `ls -a`.  Also note that if you have files _with the same name_, these would overwrite each other on the destination.

Comment: @Kusalananda i think you're right that could be the reason as 'ls -a | wc' is now giving 667, is there any way to compare both results ? the result from find command and ls -a command

Comment: @csx4 Why not compare the two `find` results? `diff <(find /tmp/files/test/ -type..... | sort )  <(find /tmp/files/pictures/ -type .... | sort)` Sorting might be needed due to the way find works.

Answer (score 0):

Could you have duplicate filenames? If so they would overwrite existing and reduce the total number of files ending up in the destination.

You could try this and see what this gives you, it should count only the numberof unique basenames of your found files:

```
find /tmp/files/test/ -type f -size -1000c -print0 | xargs -n1 -0 basename | sort | uniq | wc -l
```

Comment: i copied in empty directory how it can overwrite anything, it was hidden files issue as answered by Kuasalananda in above comments

Comment: You copy from `/tmp/files/test` _recursively_ . Any subdirectories there could contain files with the same basename. When copied to one common destination directory, they would overwrite each other in turn. Anyone arriving here later might have this issue